# C# Дан текст, в котором имеются цифры.а) Найти их сумму

Tags: c#

Есть задание : Дан текст, в котором имеются цифры.а) Найти их сумму.

Вот мой код :

```
string str7 = "На 3 минуте матча был забит гол игроком под номером 7, это его 4 гол в карьере.";
Console.WriteLine(str7);
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str7.Length; i++)
{

    if (char.IsDigit(str7[i]))
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(str7[i]);
        sum = +str7[i];
        
    }
}
Console.WriteLine($"Сумма = {sum}");
```

В числе сумма выбивает число 52 . Почему так?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32

Comment: А вы для чего конвертируете в число Convert.ToInt32(str7[i]) ? ))) а потом прибавлется код символа из строки )

Comment: `sum += Convert.ToInt32(str7[i]);`

Comment: Просто оставлю это здесь. `if (char.IsDigit(str7[i])) sum += str7[i] - '0';`

Comment: обьявил переменную до цикла summ и сделал вот так : 
summ = Convert.ToInt32(str7[i]);
                    sum += summ; - почему то получается число 158

Comment: @aepot спасибо, sum += str7[i] - '0';  - всё отлично работает, только не понял почему когда добавляем "- '0'" начинает всё отлично считать ?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten вернет код символа. Без `str7[i].ToString()` не сработает.

Comment: Никита, потому что к примеру код символа `4` на 4 больше, чем код символа `0`. Их разность дает саму цифру в виде числа. Простая хитрость. Смотрите в ASCII таблицу символов. И попробуйте `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32('0'))`, потом то же самое для четверки и посчитайте сами разницу.

Comment: @aepot понял, большое спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве примера решения вашей задачи код:

```
string str7 = "На 3 минуте матча был забит гол игроком под номером 7, это его 4 гол в карьере.";
Console.WriteLine(str7);
int sum = 0;
foreach (char ch in str7)
{
    if (int.TryParse(ch.ToString(), out int digit))
        sum += digit;
}
Console.WriteLine($"Сумма = {sum}");
```

Вы в вашем примере, используя метод Convert.ToInt32(ch):

- Получаете код символа в таблице ASCII, а не само значение цифры;
- Не присваиваете результат работы метода и он просто теряется;
- Используемая вами лексема "= +" в строке **sum = +str7[i];**, означает "присвой в переменную sum значение кода символа str7[i]". Вероятно, вы хотели написать **sum += str7[i];**.