# как сделать что бы считало сумму чисел из набора букв и цифр c#?

Tags: c#, строки, parse

Допустим пользователь пишет: 1dh2jfh3fn4
Нужно что бы вывело в консоли сумму чисел, то есть 1+2+3+4=10

Answer (score 1):

Если считать числами отдельные цифры, то:

```
using System.Linq;

///...

var input = "1dh2jfh3fn4";
var sum = input.Where(Char.IsDigit).Sum(c => c - '0');
Console.WriteLine(sum); // 10
```

Если именно числа, то с базовой поддержкой отрицательных целых:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// ...

var input = "1dh-2jfh33fn4";
var sum = Regex.Matches(input , @"-?\d+").Sum(m => Int32.Parse(m.Value));
Console.WriteLine(sum); // 36
```

Comment: а как сделать так что бы то что вводит пользователь было рандомно, то есть любой набор букв и символов, а не конкретно такой
то есть сначала он спрашивает что вы хотите ввести, потом он вводит и ему считает

Comment: @SemenBasara `Console.Write("Please enter the string: "); var input = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1200520/373567

Comment: @aepot закрыл :)